# Отправка транзакций sql через post запрос на nodeJs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, transaction, koa.js

Всем привет. Столкнулся с ошибкой sql `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Пытаюсь отправить транзакцию в связанные таблицы через post запрос.

Вот сама транзакция

```
`START TRANSACTION;
     INSERT INTO books(title, description) VALUES ('VIY','awesome');
     SET @a = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     INSERT INTO authors(author_name) VALUE ('Gogol');
     SET @b = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     INSERT INTO books_data(book_id, author_id) VALUES (@a, @b);
     COMMIT;`;
```

Отправляется банальным post запросом.
Возможно есть какие-то нюансы о которых я не знаю при отправке транзакции?
Буду благодарен любому ответу)
Использую mySQL

Вот ошибка полностью:

```
  {
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO books(title, description) VALUES ('VIY','awesome'); SET @a = LAST_IN' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO books(title, description) VALUES ('VIY','awesome'); SET @a = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO authors(author_name) VALUES ('Gogol'); SET @b = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO books_data(book_id, author_id) VALUES (@a, @b); COMMIT;"
```

}

Comment: Сделайте вот что - процитируйте ВСЁ сообщение об ошибке, абсолютно точно, включая все запятые и переводы строки (исправьте в тексте вопроса). Тогда будет предмет для разговора. Это как минимум.

Comment: @Akina, Да, вы правы. Добавил

Comment: У MySQL сообщение об ошибке цитирует текст запроса точно с того символа, где обнаружена проблема. Поскольку первый символ `I` в слове `INSERT` (как и всё слово) явно ошибкой быть не может, то проблема между этим и предыдущим символами. А она может возникнуть для приведённого текста только в том случае, когда используемый для выполнения метод не умеет выполнять мультизапросы (несколько запросов "в один присест"). Т.е. проблема не в запросе, а в том коде, который пытается его выполнить. Например, используется mysqli_query, тогда как для ТАКОГО мульти-запроса нужен mysqli_multi_query.

Comment: @Akina, крайне вам благодарен. Пойду искать проблему в методе отправки запроса.
Еще раз большое вам спасибо

Comment: Заодно настоятельно рекомендую НЕ использовать переменные. Значения идентификаторов в третьем INSERT лучше получить в соотв. SELECT. А ещё - Вы не показали структур, потому неясно, какая реакция последует на попытку ввода дублирующих записей (скажем, при обновлении страницы), но в любом случае она не будет благоприятной для результата.

Comment: @Akina, тогда нужны ли мне транзакции?

Comment: Понятия не имею. По показанному огрызку не определить, но скорее всего - в данном случае не нужны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря @Akina, Я смог решить проблему. Как он описал, проблема не в запросе, а в методе осуществляющем запрос. 
Я разбил Транзакцию на запросы и написал метод с помощью `mysql.beginTransaction`
Если кому-то будет интересно, то в комментариях будет ссылка на репозиторий с файлами. Сам метод находиться в `database -> db.js`.
Прикреплю как закончу!

Comment: https://github.com/Georgin01/Koa2-test-task